# The usual topology $\mathcal{T}$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$ make this $\frac{m(B_{\mathcal{T},r} (x_0))}{r^2}$ minimal ($m$ is a mesure)

Tags: general-topology, geometry, measure-theory

In usual topology in $\mathbb{R}^2$, we have that the area of circle of radius is $\pi r^2$. We can formulate this as:

$$\frac{m(B_r(x_0))}{r^2} = \pi,$$
where $x_0$ is an arbitrary point and $m$ is the Lebesgue mesure of our ball of radious $r$.

In taxicab topology, $$\frac{m(B_{\mathcal{Taxi}, r}(x_0))}{r^2} = 4$$

I conjecture that for any topology $\mathcal{T}$ different to usual topology, then
$$\frac{m(B_{\mathcal{T},r} (x_0))}{r^2} > \pi $$

That is the usual topology makes the quotient minimal.

Is this true?

Comment: You cannot take any topology ( or the notion of ball is void) but you need a metric. A compatible one ?

Comment: So, I need a metric space? Should I reformulate the question on metric spaces? If d is a metric, then we have inherited the concept of area of a ball of radious $r$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for the question to make sense, you have to have some relation between the metric and the measure and also assume that the metric induces the standard topology on the plane. The usual measures to consider are $\alpha$-Hausdorff measures defined by the metric, where $\alpha$ is the hausdorff dimension of your metric space. It is well-known that the Hausdorff dimension of any metric on $R^2$ is $\ge 2$. From the exponent $2$ appearing in your question, it is natural to restrict to metrics which have Hausdorff dimension 2. However, even in this class of metrics the answer is negative:

For each $\epsilon>0$ there are metrics $d$ on $R^2$ of Hausdorff dimension 2 for which there exists a center $p$ and a radius $r>0$ such that
$$
\frac{m_2(B(p,r))}{r^2}<\epsilon,
$$
where $m_2$ is the 2-dimensional Hausdorff measure.

Examples are given by cones of revolution in $R^3$. As the center $p$ you take the tip of the cone and $r=1$. Consider a sequence of cones with cone angles converging to zero. Then the above ratios converge to zero as well.

Answer (score 1):

Since you speak of balls I suspect you mean topologies from a metric. Note that in the discrete metric any ball of radius $r<1$ has Lebesgue measure 0 (as a 1-point set) and every ball of radius $r\ge1$ is just all of $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Moreover, assume you have a metric $d$ which generates the standard topology. Then, together with $d$ also $\frac{1}{M}d$ is a metric for any $M>0$ and you can make your quotient arbitrarily small.

Comment: If you have a metric $d$, then do you have inherited Lebesgue mesure, so?

Comment: The Lebesgue measure is constructed w.r.t. the standard topology, that is, you generate the Borel-$\sigma$-algebra of this topology and then do the usual construction of the respective outer measure and so on. Then, what you get is THE Lebesgue measure, wherefore to construct you need no metric. So I don't know what you mean by inheriting the measure from the metric...

Comment: I mean: if you have a metric $d$, is there any natural way (using $\sigma$-algebras if you want) to define the "area of a set" regarding to this metric? Can we replicate the construction of Lebesgue mesure with arbitrary metric $d$?

Comment: As I mentioned, if you have a topology, then you can get a Borel-$\sigma$-algebra. But already on such an Borel-$\sigma$-algebra we do not have THE measure, but many, e.g. twice the Lebesgue measure is also a measure. So the Lebesgue measure is one measure on the Borel-$\sigma$-algebra of the standard topology. So what exactly do you mean by natural way?

Comment: Continuation: If you reconsider my example of the discrete metric (which generates the discrete topology, which already is a $\sigma$-algebra), then there are many measures on that $\sigma$-algebra, but all must assign the balls of radii $r<1$ around one point the same volume. I think, whatever you mean by "natural", this metric is a counter-example.

Comment: Another continuation: And I think if you claim the metric to be nice enough, that is, that certain geometric subsets (squares etc.) are measured by their natural lengths and so on, then I think you pretty much end up with the standard metric, the standard topology and the Lebesgue measure.

Comment: So, from your words, I deduce that there is no way to define "area" from given metric $d$

Comment: No canonical way which I know.

Comment: Of course, there is a way to derive a measure from a metric $d$, it is called Hausdorff $\alpha$-measure, where $\alpha$ is  the Hausdorff dimension of $d$.

Comment: But does it give rise to the the estimate referred to in the question?

Comment: No, see examples below.